# logspout write: connection refused

Tags: logging, elasticsearch, docker, logstash, devops

I am running into an issue with error

```
# logspout v3.2-dev-custom by gliderlabs
# adapters: raw tcp logstash udp syslog
# options : persist:/mnt/routes
# jobs    : http[]:80 pump routes
# routes  :
#   ADAPTER     ADDRESS         CONTAINERS      SOURCES OPTIONS
#   logstash    0.0.0.0:5000                            map[]
2016/11/17 07:15:57 logstash: could not write:write udp 127.0.0.1:34146->127.0.0.1:5000: write: connection refused
```

after i start the adapter as 
`sudo docker run --name="logspout"     --volume=/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock     -e ROUTE_URIS=logstash://0.0.0.0:5000     c045f1a3472b`

logstash 5.0 docker container is running with the log

```
Sending Logstash's logs to /var/log/logstash which is now configured via      log4j2.properties
07:04:11.987 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.inputs.tcp -         Automatically switching from json to json_lines codec {:plugin=>"tcp"}
07:04:11.987 [[main]<udp] INFO  logstash.inputs.udp - Starting UDP listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5000"}
07:04:12.003 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.inputs.tcp - Starting tcp input listener {:address=>"0.0.0.0:5000"}
07:04:12.409 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Elasticsearch pool URLs updated {:changes=>{:removed=>[], :added=>  ["https://~hidden~:~hidden~@fc4fba7c82d6102f5c1a224f0e9f2e9a.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243"]}}
07:04:12.410 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Using mapping template from {:path=>nil}
07:04:13.612 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - Attempting to install template {:manage_template=>{"template"=>"logstash-*",  "version"=>50001, "settings"=>{"index.refresh_interval"=>"5s"}, "mappings"=>{"_default_"=>{"_all"=>{"enabled"=>true, "norms"=>false}, "dynamic_templates"=>[{"message_field"=>{"path_match"=>"message", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false}}}, {"string_fields"=>{"match"=>"*", "match_mapping_type"=>"string", "mapping"=>{"type"=>"text", "norms"=>false, "fields"=>{"keyword"=>{"type"=>"keyword"}}}}}], "properties"=>{"@timestamp"=>{"type"=>"date", "include_in_all"=>false}, "@version"=>{"type"=>"keyword", "include_in_all"=>false}, "geoip"=>{"dynamic"=>true, "properties"=>{"ip"=>{"type"=>"ip"}, "location"=>{"type"=>"geo_point"}, "latitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}, "longitude"=>{"type"=>"half_float"}}}}}}}}
07:04:13.705 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.outputs.elasticsearch - New Elasticsearch output {:class=>"LogStash::Outputs::ElasticSearch", :hosts=>["fc4fba7c82d6102f5c1a224f0e9f2e9a.us-east-1.aws.found.io:9243"]}
07:04:13.710 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.pipeline - Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>1, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>125}
07:04:13.717 [[main]-pipeline-manager] INFO  logstash.pipeline - Pipeline main started
07:04:13.802 [Api Webserver] INFO  logstash.agent - Successfully started     Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
```

I am trying to send my individual docker container logs to the elastic cloud using logspout and logstash where logstash, nginx , web etc are on the ec2 instance. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to write to localhost when I'm guessing logstash and logspout are in different containers. Can you share some more about your setup? Compose? Networking? How each container is being run?

Comment: Hey @johnharris85 ! thanks for pointing me towards the right direction. Yes, the mistake was writing it on the host rather than on the logstash container. Problem solved using legacy linking the 2 containers. Just created a docker-compose.yml with both the containers and fixed the issue. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact issue when running logstash and logspout in separate containers. In my case, logspout was trying to write to logstash before logstash was ready and this caused the logspout container to error and then crash. It was resolved by adding the RETRY_SEND environment variable to the logspout service in the docker-compose file.